# How to retrieve video AudioEncoder and VideoEncoder of a video file in android?

Tags: android

How to get AudioEncoder and VideoEncoder i.e h263,h264,aac,amr etc. of a video file in android? MediaMetadataRetriever has no such functions to retrieve these information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) (disclosure: I developed it) to retrieve the audio/video codec. Here is the corresponding code:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
String acodec = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_AUDIO_CODEC);
String vcodec = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_CODEC);
mmr.release();
```